# I want to align the social media details to be side by side(arranged column wise instead of row wise). Right now it's one under the other

Tags: html, css

I am not able to align the social media details side by side. Right now it's one under the other. I want it to be placed side by side(column wise) i.e. something like:

```
address linkedin github twitter email
```

instead of

```
address
linkedin
github
twitter
email
```

Here is the code:

```css
.contact .title::after{
    content: "";
}
/*
.contact .contact-content .column{
    width: calc(20% - 30px);
}
*/
.contact .contact-content .text{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.contact .contact-content .left p{
    text-align: justify;
}
.contact .contact-content .left .icons{
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.contact .contact-content .row{
    display: flex;
    height: 65px;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.contact .contact-content .row .info{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.contact .contact-content .row i{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #9933FF;
}
.contact .contact-content .info .head{
    font-weight: 500;
}
.contact .contact-content .info .sub-title{
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">

<section class="contact" id="contact">
    <div class="max-width">
      <h2 class="title">Reach out to Me</h2>
      <div class="contact-content">
        <div class="column left">
          <div class="text"></div>
          <div class="icons">
            <div class="row">
              <i class="uil uil-user-location"></i>
              <div class="info">
                <div class="head">Address</div>
                <div class="sub-title">country</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <a href="https://www.linkedin.com"><i class="uil uil-linkedin"></i></a>
              <div class="info">
                <div class="head">Linkedin</div>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in">
                  <div class="sub-title">xyz</div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <a href="https://github.com"><i class="uil uil-github"></i></a>
              <div class="info">
                <div class="head">Github</div>
                <a href="https://github.com">
                  <div class="sub-title">xyz</div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="uil uil-twitter"></i></a>
              <div class="info">
                <div class="head">Twitter</div>
                <a href="https://twitter.com">
                  <div class="sub-title">xyz</div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <a href="mailto:xyz@gmail.com"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
              <div class="info">
                <div class="head">Email</div>
                <a href="mailto:xyz@gmail.com">
                  <div class="sub-title">xyz@gmail.com</div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have `row: 100%;` in the class `.contact .contact-content .row` - remove this.
2. add class `.icons` with `display: flex;`

This will sort your issue.

You may also want to add padding, in which case add a class `.row` with your required padding.

Alternatively for a more responsive solution add `justify-content: space-around;` to `.icons` class.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/jonty_w/pen/qBjdVXj) with 25px padding to the right
[Demo](https://codepen.io/jonty_w/pen/eYRNeEJ) with `space-around`

Comment: This solves my issue. Thank you so much!!